# Set multiple images as background on Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, desktop-background

I have multiple images and want to set them as desktop background. Something like `image1.jpg`, `image2.jpg`, `image3.jpg`.
I want to rotate the desktop background between these images like first `image1.jpg` should be background and after 5 min `image2.jpg` and so on.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Shotwell (should be pre-installed with Ubuntu 18.04LTS)

If you've not used it before, you'll need to wait for it to import the photos on your system.

Highlight the pictures you want to form the slide show (`Ctrl`+`left-click` to select multiple pictures)

Click on the File menu at the top and select 'Set as Desktop Slideshow'. You then get options to change how frequently the picture changes, and whether it's on the desktop or the lock screen or both.